# Potential leak of an object allocated in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

when i am analyze my project following code gives me leakage warning. is there any way to solve my memory leakage problem ?

warning :

```
Potential leak of an object allocated on line 38 and stored into 'addressBook'
```

Bellow is my code.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    m_tableDataArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];
    NSMutableArray *listDate = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    NSArray *addresses = (NSArray *) ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    NSInteger addressesCount = [addresses count];
    for (int i = 0; i < addressesCount; i++) {
        ABRecordRef record = [addresses objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *firstName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        NSString *lastName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        if(firstName != nil && lastName != nil){
            NSString *contactFirstLast = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
            [listDate addObject:contactFirstLast];
        }
        [firstName release];
        [lastName release];
    }
    m_tableDataArray = [[NSArray arrayWithArray:listDate] retain];
    [addresses release];
    addresses = nil;
    [m_mainTable reloadData];
}
```

Thanks in adv...

Comment: You have to release whatever you create/copy. In this case, ABAdressBookCreate() is creating an address book ref and you are not releasing it anywhere.

Comment: you mean this object i have to release ?  `ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();`

Comment: explain your code Men's What is addressBook,record Some thing like this. then some one can help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have finished using `addressBook` you need to release it using:

```
CFRelease(addressBook);
```

This should probably be placed at the end of your `viewWillAppear:` method.

**Updated:** There are a few unnecessary arrays and steps in your version of `viewWillAppear:`.  I have cleaned it up a bit and fixed a potential memory leak.

Note: I haven't actually run this so double-check that it works correctly.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // I assume m_tableDataArray is an instance variable.  If so, if the 
    // view appears multiple times it will result in a leak unless we 
    // release pre-existing instances first.

    [m_tableDataArray release], m_tableDataArray = nil;
    m_tableDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

    NSArray *addresses = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

    for (ABRecordRef record in addresses) {
        NSString *firstName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        NSString *lastName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

        if(firstName != nil && lastName != nil){
            NSString *contactFirstLast = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
            [m_tableDataArray addObject:contactFirstLast];
        }

        [firstName release];
        [lastName release];
    }

    [addresses release], addresses = nil;
    CFRelease(addressBook);

    [m_mainTable reloadData];
}
```