# Potential leak of an object stored in $object

Tags: ios

At line 3 and 4, I get a **Product --> Analyze** message

> Potential leak of an object stored in `source`
>
> Potential leak of an object stored in `addressbook`

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
```

Would you be tell the reason for those messages and how not to get those?

Comment: release them after they are not needed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Potential leak of an object allocated in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069094/potential-leak-of-an-object-allocated-in-iphone)

Comment: thanks....I think you helped me fix it....